# Making Beyond compare work in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, merge, compare, beyondcompare

I'm working with PyDev on Ecplise and i want to make Beyond Compare my tool for merge/diff
I read in several places regarding the var and configuration but nothing seems to work
I've installed the SVN plugin.
I've notices there are 3 places to configure :

```
SVN -> Diff viewer  
SVN -> Diff/Merge  
Ext. Tools -> Beyond Compare
```

I've set the first to the path of "BComp.exe" and vars in the first box to :

```
"${base}" "${mine}"
/lefttitle="Base ${base}"
/righttitle="Local ${mine}"
```

The second box vars are :

```
"${theirs}" "${yours}" "${base}" "${merged}"
/lefttitle="Incoming (${theirs})"
/centertitle="Base (${base})"
/righttitle="Local (${yours})"
/outputtitle="Merged (${merged})"
/solo
```

in SVN->Diff/Merge i set parameters to :

```
"${theirs}" "${yours}" "${base}" "${merged}" /lefttitle="Incoming (${theirs})" /centertitle="Base (${base})" /righttitle="Local (${yours})" /outputtitle="Merged (${merged})" /solo
```

In the Beyond Compare sub menu i selected the path to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe
```

When i select 2 files and click to compare i get the following message :

```
Unable to start Beyond Compare.
Please check the preference page and make sure the information there is valid
Exception: Please select at least on valid resource
```

What is the wrong configuration ?

Thank you

Comment: It might be helpful to share the information that you currently have in your preference page.